# Windows installation not identified. ?? Boot Configuration data file BCD error code " 0xc0000024"

Tags: bcd

The day just kept getting better!...  I was in safe mode tidying up the loose ends of my compromised security ordeal only to be met with this message: `"Windows 10 boot configuration data file is missing some required information File:'BCD error code " 0xc0000024`.

I would greatly appreciate any help that anyone can send my way.  Note: I do have another working PC on hand here if there are tasks that I will need to access the internet for downloads, etc.

I found these commands online and tried with the following results.
From command prompt:

1. `bootrec /fixmbr {The operation completed successfully}`
2. `bootrec /fixboot{The operation completed successfully}`
3. `bootrec /rebuildbcd {This may take a while…}`

   The message is there is no Windows installation to identify…operation was successful?

   This computer is less than a year old and came with Windows 10 so I am at a loss here-confused.  Any help would be super!

Answer (score 0):

It certainly looks like your boot configuration data is corrupted. You might have done this unintentionally as you were,

> in safe mode tidying up the loose ends of my compromised security
>   ordeal

I'd suggest you repair your system either using a DVD or USB stick containing Windows installation media. If have have a 64bit OS have the 64 bit windows installation media vice versa.

- After booting from the media try to "Automatically repair your system" in advanced menu options.
- Try perfoming the earlier commands agsin.

Any corrupted system files should be restored